# Is it necessary to check contrains when solving absolute vlaue inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, let's say we have an absolute quadratic function $f(x)$ which is equal to $|g(x)|$, a quadratic function

When faced with solving the following inequality: $f(x) < a$ we have $-g(x)$ if $g(x) < 0$ and $g(x)$ if $g(x) \ge 0$

So if we then solve both inequalities, $g(x) \lt a$ and $g(x) > -a$ is it necessary to check the absolute value constraints?

I.e., does there ever exist the following situation?

Say we use $-g(x)$ when $x \gt 5$

Then we solve for $g(x) > -a$ and we get $x \lt 3$

Clearly when $x \lt 3$ we would not be using $-g(x)$ but instead $g(x)$

Would such a situation ever happen, or is this impossible?  Do I ever have to check for such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x) = |g(x)|$ a quadratic function? What functions do you have in mind? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, for example $g(x) = x^2+3x-1$ and $f(x)=|g(x)|=|x^2+3x-1|$

Comment: I see. But in this case $f(x)$ is not a quadratic function anymore, so your formulation was confusing! I wouldn't call $f(x)$ an "absolute quadratic function", but rather "the absolute value of a quadratic".

Comment: Okay, thank you for the correction. So am I right to assume that I have to check the constraints as well? Or can I just solve for g(x) < a and g(x) > -a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $f(x) = |g(x)| < a$ is equivalent to $-a < g(x) < a$. So you have to solve for both ($g(x) < a$ and $-a < g(x)$), and then take the points they have in common ; this will give you your set of solutions. Your idea of "using $g(x)$ instead of $-g(x)$ and/or vice-versa" is simply confusing you, sadly. Don't worry about it.

Hope that helps,